# Continuous deployment to Azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-git-deployment

I have set up a Git hook in Azure. However, whenever I try to push to Azure VM, I am stuck with this screen, and it freezes. I am using the same keys that SSH into the azure virtual machine.

[image: stucked here.]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git - Server host key not cached](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931384/git-server-host-key-not-cached)

Comment: @peter It is not a not a duplicate.