# Connection abandoned. fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, github, cmd

I have a github repo, like https://github.com/username/reponame

I have also [added](https://help.github.com/en/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account) my SSH key to the repo in the settings.

Using:

```
git remote -v
```

I get:

```
reponame        git@github.com:username/reponame.git (fetch)
reponame        git@github.com:username/reponame.git (push)
```

I've made a `test.txt` in the repo root on Github to test fetching.

Using the git command in Windows CMD in the local project folder (which was copied earlier from the repo manually),

```
git fetch reponame
```

I get:

```
The server's host key is not cached in the registry. You
have no guarantee that the server is the computer you
think it is.
The server's rsa2 key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa 2048 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Connection abandoned.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I've found same questions but none of them could clear the picture for me.

Any suggestion what am I missing here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git - Server host key not cached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931384/git-server-host-key-not-cached)

Comment: @WanderNauta I've found this post, that answer makes no sense to me. How do I see the hostkey of my ```projectname```?

Comment: In your case, you would try `ssh git@github.com`. It should ask you whether you want to continue connecting. Answering yes adds the host key. If GitHub then greets you with your username, `git fetch` should now succeed.

Comment: @WanderNauta Already tried that: 
```PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Hi Username! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
Connection to github.com closed.```

Comment: Yes, like I said, GitHub has now greeted you with your username. The `git fetch` should now succeed.

Comment: @WanderNauta Thanks for trying to help, but it does not. I'm sure I'm missing something. ```git fetch``` does nothing, and ```git fetch reponame``` shows the same message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but changing to HTTPS instead of SSH access has worked.

```
git remote rm reponame
git remote add reponame https://github.com/username/reponame.git
```